# Why single-{slug}.php not calling in wordpress for single post display?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Hey everyone I am facing trouble calling single-{slug}.php in wordpress when I am displaying a particular post.

For example I have post called php so I have created a file single-php.php in twentyseventeen folder of themes directory but it is not calling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the correction

```
single-{post-type}-{slug}.php – (Since 4.4) First, WordPress looks for a template for the specific post. For example, if post type is product and the post slug is dmc-12, WordPress would look for single-product-dmc-12.php.
```

Reference : [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

So it will be single-post-{slug}.php for single post.